# Error: No word lists can be found for the language "en_US"

Tags: flycheck, ispell

I am using `GNU Emacs 26.1` on macOS Catalina.

When I try to enable `ispell` or `flycheck-mode` I am getting following error:

```
No word lists can be found for the language "en_US".
```

=> How could I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing `aspell` fixed my problem.

```
brew install aspell
```

Answer (score 3):

Package `aspell` comes with Debian 11, but evidently lacks dictionaries.

```bash
sudo apt-get install aspell-en
```

Installs the English spelling dictionary for `aspell`.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem on Fedora 34.

```
sudo dnf install aspell-en
```

fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Manjaro 21 also lacks dictionaries.

```
sudo pacman -S aspell-en
```

fix the problem.