# Error enabling Flyspell mode (Error: No word lists can be found for the language "en_US")

Tags: spacemacs, flyspell

I recently saw my emacs (GNU Emacs 27.1 running on Arch Linux) throw this error:

```
Error enabling Flyspell mode:
(Error: No word lists can be found for the language "en_US".)
```

when I visited a markdown file. My emacs is configured to use the latest commit on the develop branch of [spacemacs](https://www.spacemacs.org/). Any idea how I can allow Flyspell to find a word list?

I tried the solution from [Error: No word lists can be found for the language "en_US"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53885/error-no-word-lists-can-be-found-for-the-language-en-us), which was to simply install `aspell`, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Please don't post the same question to StackOverflow and emacs.SE. Please delete one of them. Thx.

Comment: Sure. I've deleted the duplicate StackOverflow question.

Comment: Thank you......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One needs to install additional dictionaries used either by ispell or, in your case, aspell programs: there are corresponding packages for them
(looks like [this](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/aspell-en/), I'm not on arch, so can not speak for this).

You can see what kind of languages are available using `M-x spell-checking/change-dictionary`.

Comment: None of these functions exists in my Emacs 26.1.